# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "CLASSES" not found

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I built a JPA app that inserts successfully into a database.  I then built a Java EE web app that works fine.  I then attempted to add the same files in the JPA app into the Java EE web app.  For some reason, even though the JPA app works like a champ, the same files in the Java EE web app throw:

Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "CLASSES" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO classes.classes (id, associated_term, credit_hours, days, description, instructor_name, lab_info, location, name, registration_levels, schedule_type, seats_available, time, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [90079-173]

Side note, I have a schema named "classes", and a table in that schema named "classes".  I am using the exact same persistence.xml file in both apps... How could one do just fine, and the other fail to recognize the CLASSES schema?  I'm befuddled.  Here's more info...

[image: Project Structure]

From persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="JPADemo">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.jared.tutoring.model.courses.Classes</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classes" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="letmein!" />

        <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="SEVERE" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

From Bean.java

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import com.jared.jpa.demo.JpaTest;

@ManagedBean
public class Bean {

    public void doDbStuff() {
        JpaTest jpaTest = new JpaTest();
        jpaTest.doDBStuff();
    }

}
```

From Classes.java

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Classes generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "classes", catalog = "classes")
public class Classes implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String associatedTerm;
    private String registrationLevels;
    private String creditHours;
    private String instructorName;
    private String location;
    private String labInfo;
    private String days;
    private String time;
    private String scheduleType;
    private String seatsAvailable;
    private String type;

...
```

From JpaTest.java

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import com.jared.tutoring.model.courses.Classes;

public class JpaTest {

    public void doDBStuff() {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPADemo");
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();

        Classes dummyClass = createDummyCourse();

        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        try {
            manager.persist(dummyClass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        manager.getTransaction().commit();

        System.out.println(".. done");
    }


    private Classes createDummyCourse() {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(100000);

        Classes newClass = new Classes();
        newClass.setId("NewId" + randomNum);
        newClass.setName("Course Name" + randomNum);
        newClass.setDescription("Course Description" + randomNum);
        newClass.setAssociatedTerm("Assocaiated Term" + randomNum);
        newClass.setRegistrationLevels("Registration Levels" + randomNum);
        newClass.setCreditHours("Credit Hours" + randomNum);
        newClass.setInstructorName("Instructor Name" + randomNum);
        newClass.setLocation("Location" + randomNum);
        newClass.setLabInfo("Lab Info" + randomNum);
        newClass.setDays("Days");
        newClass.setTime("Time");
        newClass.setScheduleType("Schedule Type");
        newClass.setSeatsAvailable("Seats Avaliable");
        newClass.setType("Type");

        return newClass;
    }

}
```

Just a reminder, this same persistence.xml file, and the same code to insert into the DB are all in another non-web project that works like a champ.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a side note, if anyone wants more info, please let me know and I'll update the above with the added information.

Comment: "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:" - h2? That's a completely different database than MySQL. Whatever is tripping this exception, its not in what you posted.